# How to swap two wxWindows in two different notebooks?

Tags: wxwidgets

Our app is build on wxWidgets and designed to work on two displays. Each display has one wxAuiNotebook which in turn have one wxGLCanvas that we're rendering to.

I'd like a hotkey to be able to switch the two wxGLCanvas windows, so the user experience is that the canvas that was on Monitor #2 is now rendering to #1 and vise versa. (There are a bunch of toolbars and widgets surrounding the canvases, but I don't want them to switch displays.)

wxGLCanvas is a subclass of wxWindow, so I'm guessing it can happen at the level. What functions calls should I be looking at to accomplish this?

Sorry about the vagueness of my question. It aligns with my level of understanding of wxWidgets.

Comment: so you want only GL canvas to swap or notebooks as well?

Comment: @Igor, just the GL canvas

Comment: you can try to call Reparent(). Check the documentation if its available for GLCanvas though. In any case, if you have a toolbars and menus on those notebooks you will probably need them switch as well. Also, problem might arise since the 2 monitors can have different resolution, and especially on GTK, things may not work out of the box. See recent threads about HiDPI on wx-dev archive.

Comment: Reparent did the job! (I don't need the toolbars to follow.) The two monitors are the same size but the canvases aren't and they aren't resizing to fit their new windows, even when I explicitly call their OnSize handlers. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You could indeed use `Reparent()`, but for two `wxGLCanvas`es it would make much more sense to simply use pointers to them in your code and just flip them when you want to switch them because it's just their contents that matters and not the windows themselves.

Comment: The gl-context is "joined" to the *handle to a device context* for the window [MS doc](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/windows/desktop/dd374379(v=vs.85).aspx). So, I doubt just swapping pointers is enough. If some body has tried it successfully I'd like to know about.

Comment: [This datenwolf guru-answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44840267/will-wglcreatecontext-fail-safely-if-a-directx-context-already-exists-for-the) says that VZ is right, HDC is swappable if the pixel format are compatible.

Comment: What methods would I used to swap pointers? As a test, I tried to remove a wxGLCanvas and add it back to the same window using notebook->RemovePage( canvas->GetID() ) and notebook->AddPage( canvas ). It remove the canvas rendering but it didn't come back

Comment: What do you mean by "what methods would I use?"? It's your code, use whichever methods you have. This has nothing to do with wxWidgets, it's an _alternative_ way of doing the same thing. If you really want to switch windows, then use `Reparent()` as mentioned.

Comment: @VZ, which wx methods to use is what I was after. Is wxGLContext::SetCurrent() what you were suggesting and "flipping" the pointer I passed? If so, that didn't work for me, maybe because I have a context for each canvas.